# Comentar una linea en un fichero.log separado por espacios en blanco?

Tags: bash, shell, centos

fichero.log

```
if $programname contains 'file_apps_' then  @233.33.3.3

$ModLoad fdsf

#File APPS  - j_d
action(type="dfsfdsf")
$InputFileName /logs/.log
$InputFileTag ja_dd_d
$InputFileStateFile jas_dd_d
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local7
$InputRunFileMonitor


#File APPS  - j_d
#action(type="dfsfdsf")
#$InputFileName /logs/.log
#$InputFileTag ja_dd_d
#$InputFileStateFile jas_dd_d
#$InputFileSeverity info
#$InputFileFacility local7
#$InputRunFileMonitor
```

Quiero que se me comenten las lineas

```
$InputFileName /logs/.log
$InputFileTag ja_dd_d
```

se podria hacer con un sed pero he probado y nada...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma simple de usar `sed` para comentar las líneas que coincidan con un cierto patrón consiste en "seleccionar" esas líneas con una expresión regular, y "aplicarles" la sustitución del "inicio de línea" por el carácter `#`. Es decir:

```
sed '/expresion-regular/s/^/#/g' < entrada > salida
```

El "quiz" aquí es la expresión regular que debes usar, y qué versión de `sed` uses pues los detalles de la sintaxis varían entre versiones.

La expresión regular puede ser tan simple como una palabra, pero en este caso parece que son dos las que buscas. Una expresión regular como la siguiente te seleccionará las líneas que comiencen por `"$InputFileName"` o por `"$InputFileTag"`:

```
/^(\$InputFileName|\$InputFileTag)/
```

de hecho, ya que ambas cadenas empiezan igual, puedes ponerlo también así:

```
/^\$InputFile(Name|Tag)/
```

Fíjate que el `$` debe llevar un `\` delante para "escaparle" su significado especial en una expresión regular.

Ahora, para usar esa expresión regular en `sed`, hay que añadir algunos caracteres extra dependiendo de qué versión de `sed` uses:

- **GNU sed** (Es la versión que viene en Linux)

  En esta versión hay que escapar también los paréntesis y el `|`, por lo que debes usar:

  ```
  sed '/^\$InputFile\(Name\|Tag\)/s/^/#/g' < entrada > salida
  ```
- **BSD sed** (es la versión que viene en OSX)

  En esta versión no hay que escapar paréntesis, y el `|` no lo entiende por defecto, pero lo admitirá si añades la opción `-E`. Por tanto:

  ```
  sed -E  '/^\$InputFile(Name|Tag)/s/^/#/g' < entrada > salida
  ```

Una vez hayas comprobado (mirando el fichero `salida`) que te ha funcionado correctamente, puedes cambiar la sintaxis por esta otra, para modificar directamente el fichero de entrada:

```
sed -i '..lo_antes_dicho...'  entrada
```

Comment: y si hubiera otro lineas debajo comentadas como las descomento ejemplo de fichero.log edito la pregunta.

Comment: Tienes que ser más específico sobre cómo distinguir las líneas que quieres descomentar de las que no. La idea es la misma, hacer una expresión regular que encaje con las líneas en cuestión y aplicarles la sustitución del primer `#` por la cadena vacía: `sed '/expresion-regular/s/^#//g'`